# Log4j2 rolling over file with wrong timestamp

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2 -
org.apache.logging.log4j-log4j-api-2.14.1.jar

and for clean up policy, I am using CronbasedTriggerPolicy, after adding cron based trigger policy, whenever log4j2 rolls over the files, it replaces the date and time stamp with 0's

This is how my config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile fileName="data/appname-${date:yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:SSS}.gz" filePattern="data/appname-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS}.%03i.gz" name="AppAppender">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%-6p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1}: %m%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="*/5 * * * *"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="data/" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*appname-*.gz"/>
                    <IfLastModified age="1d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger additivity="false" name="com.app.Test">
            <AppenderRef ref="AppAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When logs are being written to file file looks like this -
`appname-2021-10-28_16:35:01:393.gz`

After rolling over file changes to this-
`appname-2021-10-28_00:00:00.000.001.gz`

Why is log4j2 changing the timestamp to all 0s? and this started happening after I added the cron trigger policy, if I remove it, things work as expected. My final agenda is to have log4j2 delete all files that are older than 2 weeks. I am just playing with the config for a day right now.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I am not still not clear on why cron trigger would change the timestamp to all 0s, I achieved what I wanted to achieve, my understanding of delete tag was not clear enough. I read through the log4j2 documentation and I realized I missed the part where they explained that delete works whenever roll over happens, for my needs I realized there was no need to have cron trigger policy in first place. The delete would have tried to run every time log4j2 rolls over the file.